# Hibernate пытается создать существующую таблицу

Tags: java, hibernate

Просмотрел массы ссылок, везде проблемы что таблицы не создаются, у меня другая история, пытается создать таблицу, которая есть, на работоспособность не влияет, но если есть такое поведение, значит что-то не так.

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    create table shСorrespondent (
       rid int8 not null,
        inn varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (rid)
    )" via JDBC Statement
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: отношение "shСorrespondent" уже существует

Класс:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="shСorrespondent")
public class ShСorrespondent {
    @Id
    private long rid;
    private String name;
    private String inn;

    public ShСorrespondent() {
    }

    public ShСorrespondent(long rid, String name) {
        this.rid = rid;
        this.name = name;
    }

далее геттеры и сеттеры

}
```

Аналогичный класс таких проблем не вызывает, определяется как не требующий создания/обновления.

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "sunit")
public class ShPlaceSale {
    @Id
    private Integer rid;
    private String name;

    public ShPlaceSale() {
    }

    public Integer getRid() {
        return rid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



}
```

Настройка xml  -     `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`
Версия 5.4.3

Вопрос, где я недосмотрел и что вызывает такое поведения Hibernate?

Comment: Пробовали вручную удалить из базы таблицу и дать хибернейту создать ее самостоятельно с параметром hbm2.ddl = update?

Comment: значения  в таблице это  внешний ключ для другой таблицы, а другая таблица ключ на следующей  --  поскольку работает  - не хочется идти на подобные меры).

Comment: Сделайте бэкап базы и попробуйте

Comment: после того как Hibernate создал таблицу, при повторном запуске, та же ситуация. В добавок и констрэйнты добавились по ключам, но это мелочи.

Comment: А если попробовать все таблицы с нуля создать хибернейтом? Вопоос я так понимаю исключительно с этой одной таблицей?

Comment: Все таблицы это проблема, тк база заполнена разными проектами для одной цели, какие то руками, часть Hbernate одного проекта, другая часть Hibernate из другого проекта.

Да, проблема только в одной таблице, при выставленном параметре  hbm2.ddl = update. Но все работает, просто ошибки в логах при запуске.

Comment: Тут похожая проблема. Может найдете решение своей: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-5-2-14-ddl-update-tries-to-recreate-tables-in-oracle/907

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил изменением имени таблицы с:

```
@Table (name="shСorrespondent")
```

на:

```
@Table (name="shcorrespondent")
```